# How do I remove the header in RMarkdown for descr()?

Tags: r, summarytools

I am trying to create a basic descriptive summary table in my RMarkdown pdf document.

```
data(iris)
library(summarytools)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  descr(Sepal.Length, stats = "fivenum", headings = FALSE)
```

I get the following output:

```
Descriptive Statistics  
Sepal.Length by Species  
Data Frame: iris  
N: 50  

               setosa   versicolor   virginica
------------ -------- ------------ -----------
         Min     4.30         4.90        4.90
          Q1     4.80         5.60        6.20
      Median     5.00         5.90        6.50
          Q3     5.20         6.30        6.90
         Max     5.80         7.00        7.90
```

How do I get rid of this part from the final output?:

```
Descriptive Statistics  
Sepal.Length by Species  
Data Frame: iris  
N: 50
```

I assumed `headings = FALSE` was going to do it, but I guess I was wrong! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fixed soon, but in the meantime, this will work:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  descr(Sepal.Length, stats = "fivenum") %>% 
  print(headings = FALSE)

##                setosa   versicolor   virginica
## ------------ -------- ------------ -----------
##          Min     4.30         4.90        4.90
##           Q1     4.80         5.60        6.20
##       Median     5.00         5.90        6.50
##           Q3     5.20         6.30        6.90
##          Max     5.80         7.00        7.90
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `tb` to get rid of the "descriptive" part above and then `kable` for making a nice table for `Rmarkdown` outputs. For example:

```
library(summarytools)
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        descr(Sepal.Length, stats = "fivenum") %>%
        tb() %>%
        knitr::kable()
```

Output:

```
|Species    |variable     | min|  q1| med|  q3| max|
|:----------|:------------|---:|---:|---:|---:|---:|
|setosa     |Sepal.Length | 4.3| 4.8| 5.0| 5.2| 5.8|
|versicolor |Sepal.Length | 4.9| 5.6| 5.9| 6.3| 7.0|
|virginica  |Sepal.Length | 4.9| 6.2| 6.5| 6.9| 7.9|
```

We could also transpose the table using `t()`. For example:

```
iris %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        descr(Sepal.Length, stats = "fivenum") %>%
        tb() %>%
        t() %>%
        knitr::kable()
```

```
|         |             |             |             |
|:--------|:------------|:------------|:------------|
|Species  |setosa       |versicolor   |virginica    |
|variable |Sepal.Length |Sepal.Length |Sepal.Length |
|min      |4.3          |4.9          |4.9          |
|q1       |4.8          |5.6          |6.2          |
|med      |5.0          |5.9          |6.5          |
|q3       |5.2          |6.3          |6.9          |
|max      |5.8          |7.0          |7.9          |
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "variable" row that contains "Sepal.Length"?

Comment: @hy9fesh in the second table?

Comment: Yes, the second table.

Comment: @hy9fesh you could for instance insert `select(-variable) %>%` between `tb()` and `t()`